# Como ao ler um arquivo txt armazenar o valor no tipo inteiro?

Tags: java, android

Estou utilizando este exemplo:

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("nome-do-arquivo.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String linha;

    while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
      nome = linha;
       id = bufferedReader.readLine() // Aqui é um tipo inteiro
    }
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No `arquivo txt` está assim

```
fulano
R.drawble.image
```

Gostaria como fazer `R.drawble.image` armazenar num tipo inteiro pois tentei converte de `String` para `int` mas não deu certo.

Comment: Você quer armazenar um texto numa variável `int`?

Comment: @jbueno não é isso, é na hora de ler gravar numa variável tipo inteiro `int`

Comment: @jbueno `R.drawable.image ` ele é do tipo inteiro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar algo assim no seu `while`:

```
while ((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (linha.startsWith("R.drawble.")) {
        String name = linha.replace("R.drawble.", "");
        int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Onde `resource` será o inteiro correspondente ao *drawable* do seu aplicativo.

Comment: não entendi poderia comentar o código para ver se da uma luz

Comment: O que você quer, é que a partir da linha que você tem em seu *txt*, você obtenha o inteiro que corresponde a um *drawable* do seu aplicativo, não é?

Comment: sim é isso estou com duvida nessa parte `String name = linha.replace("R.drawble.", "");`

Comment: É porque pelo método `getIdentifier()`, o primeiro parâmetro é o nome do *drawable*, daí é preciso excluir o "R.drawable." da sua linha e utilizar somente a parte que interessa, que é o nome em si.

Comment: entendi, vou testar

Answer (score 1):

Como dito pelo @Paulo Rodrigues , você pode utilizar o método `getIdentifier` do Resource.

[Segue a documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

Exemplo de utilização:

```
   try {
        AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("nome-do-arquivo.txt");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String linha;


        while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            String id = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if(id.contains(".")){ // garantimos que haja pontos na string...
                String[] valores = id.split("."); // quebramos a string nos pontos {"R", "rawble", image"}
                // Vamos pegar sua identificação conforme os valores...
                int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(valores[2], valores[1], getActivity().getPackageName());
            }


        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```